# Who buys the 'Stranded' items?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Who buys the 'Stranded' items such as 'Stranded Shackles' or 'Stranded Figure', and where can I find them?

The items are purple-coloured, and have "Trading with Merchants" in the "used for" list, but none of the specialist merchants I've found so far will buy the special items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://segmentnext.com/2017/03/02/horizon-zero-dawn-stranded-collectibles-guide/), there is a merchant in Meridian who will trade these items for a modification box.

Fun fact: the 3 "Stranded" items are actually a [Death Stranding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Stranding?wprov=sfsi1) easter egg!

> Having collected all three Horizon Zero Dawn Stranded Collectibles, players can take them to the Mysterious Boxes merchant in Meridian and trade in for a Mysterious Box. The box grants players the following items:
>
> - Special Modification Box – rare weapon or outfit modification
> - Modification Box – random weapon or outfit modification
> - Shard Gambler’s Box – metal shards
> - Warm Socks – can be sold to merchants for 100 Metal Shards, it is unclear whether this has any other use or not

The merchant can be found here:

> [image: specialty merchant location]

[Source for image](http://m.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/Stranded_Items)